# Ошибка в сравнении

Tags: javascript

Условие: Пользователь вводит номер месяца. Вывести название времени года (весна, лето, осень, зима).

Ошибка: выводит только зиму.

вот код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тестом код приведите

Comment: У тебя в первом же условии a сравнивается с 12 и если оно дает false то идет следующая проверка - 1 - не сравнивается ни с чем, а просто приводится к булевому типу и дает `true`. Правильно писать так `a == 12 || a == 1`, а еще правильнее для этих целей юзать `switch`

Comment: потому что у вас условие не правильное

Answer (score 5):

не проще ли сделать так

```
console.log(['зима','весна','лето','осень'][Math.floor(month/3%4)])
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что пользователь ещё новичок и предложенный вами вариант затруднит его понимание.

Comment: Может и так, но разбираться в куче ифов мне кажется не менее простым делом

Comment: @Blacit Хотя бы уж так `if ([12,1,2].indexOf(a) != -1) {`, если через if

Comment: Да пользователь пусть сам выбирает как лучше, моё дело подсказать :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (a == 12 || a == 1 || a == 2) {
  // и так далее
```

Answer (score 1):

Твоя проблема заключалась в том, что ты не сравнивал переменную "a" с тем, что указывал в скобках. Я предоставил правильный вариант твоего кода:

```
if (a == 12 || a == 1 || a == 2) {
console.log("Зима")
} else if (a == 3 || a == 4 || a == 5) {
console.log("Весна")
} else if (a == 6 || a == 7 || a == 8) {
console.log("Лето")
} else if (a == 9 || a == 10 || a == 11) {
console.log("Осень")
} else {
console.log("Ошибка")
}
```